# getRequest.getParameter("param1") Returning Empty For Element.value

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, action, get-request

I am trying to run an ajax call with jqGrid. However, the parameters are not being sent to the getRequest() all of the time.

If I do the javascript:

```
var param1 = document.getElementById("idInput").value;
var url = "${ctx}/Method.action?getTheseRecords&param1="+param1;
```

Then when I call in the Java it comes back blank. However, I if set the var param1, then I get the right data.

So this works:

```
var param1 = "M";
var url = "${ctx}/Method.action?getTheseRecords&param1="+param1;
```

So the first way gives an empty String, and the second gives a String == "M":

```
String param1 = getRequest().getParameter("param1");
```

I don't know if somebody knows why this isn't working? Because I have looked at the url before putting it into the Ajax, and it is fine.

Comment: Check if the `idInput` field name matches correctly and it has value. That will answer.

Comment: I have a feeling this will answer your question ~ [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: I have had that problem a lot with jQuery as well. Thanks Phil! This problem turned out to be an error for how I was calling every search after the initial with reload.

Answer (score 0):

You do not encode your url. That might be the problem.

```
var url = "${ctx}/Method.action?getTheseRecords&param1=" + encodeURIComponent(param1);
```

Other than that, everything seems fine to me.

Comment: Good advice in general but I can pretty much guarantee this won't solve the problem.

Comment: I did do something like that. I found out what the problem was. The jqGrid was reloading with the original url. So I needed to change the url during the reload. This was just a rookie mistake on my part. Thank you